# Using Regex to delete contents between repeating brackets

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to remove unneeded words between brackets that contains certain modifier ('DeleteMe') and don't delete contents between brackets that contains other words ('DontDeleteMe').
I though it was simple but proved difficult due to repeating brackets see below.

```
[
aljdsfjfldsa      DeleteMe         aldsjflajdf
]
[
aldskjfal         DontDeleteMe     asdlkjflasdj
]
[
aljdsfjfldsa      DeleteMe         aldsjflajdf
]
[
aldskjfal         DontDeleteMe     asdlkjflasdj
]
```

Desired output

```
[
aldskjfal         DontDeleteMe     asdlkjflasdj
]
[
aldskjfal         DontDeleteMe     asdlkjflasdj
]
```

I tried the following but the problem is the second line will be deleted with the third line.

```
(?s)\[.*?'DeleteMe'.*?\]
```

Comment: What have you tried, which langage/tool ?

Comment: I tried regex in BBedit to modify the content of html file, and also happy to try python script

Comment: This is a common issue. `.` matches any char, you need `[^][]`. `\[[^][]*'DeleteMe'[^][]*]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary in combination with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

```
\[[^][]*\bDontDeleteMe\b[^][]*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VmAzgE/1)

If the word is `DeleteMe` you can match it using word boundaries and repace with an empty string.

```
\[[^][]*\bDeleteMe\b[^][]*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTO4Kw/1)